# Dropzone - How to make div to dropzone (not form) and autoProcessQueue:false

Tags: javascript, jquery, dropzone.js

I'm searching the method to make div into dropzone, because I want the dropzone stay inside other html form.

so I found the jquery method

```
<script>
Dropzone.autoDiscover = false;
    jQuery(document).ready(function() {

      $("#mydropzone").dropzone({
        url: "path/to/file",
        autoProcessQueue: false
      });

    });

    $(document).on('click', '#btn_special', function () {
    // enable auto process queue after uploading started
    Dropzone.options.autoProcessQueue = true;
    // queue processing
    Dropzone.processQueue();  ///////////// it's not work ///////
    });

</script>

<form action="some_page.php" method="post">
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>Member Name</td>
        <td><input type="text" name="member_name" /> </td>
    </tr>

</table>

    <div class="dropzone dropzone-previews" id="mydropzone"> <!-- My dropzone stay at this --></div>

    <button type="button" id="btn_special">Upload</button>
    <input type="submit" name="submit_htmlform" value="submit" />
</form>
```

..
The Problem is I don't know the jquery method to make dropzone submit( Dropzone.processQueue(); ) I know only javascript method.  but also I don't know javascript method to convert the div element to dropzone. How should I do?

Comment: change `Dropzone.processQueue(); ` by `$("#mydropzone").dropzone().processQueue();`

Comment: sorry not working.

Answer (score 0):

Try to change your js like this :

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
   var myDropZone = $("#mydropzone").dropzone({
     url: "path/to/file",
     autoProcessQueue: false,
   });
   $(document).on('click', '#btn_special', function () {
        myDropZone.options.autoProcessQueue = true;
        myDropZone.processQueue();
   });
});
```

Comment: Does `#mydropzone` exist? Should be `#dropzone_special`?

Comment: What your js console tell you ?

Comment: Check if the url is correct and put some console.log in your code because I don't see why it doesn't work. Do you also add your js in your HTML?

Comment: yes I add it.   I search this javascript method that can use processQueue();  https://github.com/enyo/dropzone/wiki/Upload-all-files-with-a-button     ................but cannot use on div element? you see his example use on form element.  this work fine but cannot use on div